# Creating Folders and Moving Images from a single folder using Python

Tags: python, parsing, shutil

Hi I have a folder which consists of a 1000 images all of which are png. The file name is 1.png, 2.png, 3.png ... all up to 1000.

Instead of manually making 10 sub folders to copy and paste the images into each sub folder, I want to move the first 100 images to folder 1, the second batch of images i.e. 101-200 to folder 2, 201-300 to folder 3 and so on until folder 10.

Is it possible that some python code that can parse through the name of the images and create a new folder and move the relevant images there?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using pathlib. This code was tested in python 3.8 but it should work on other versions too.

```
from pathlib import Path

#0-99 (folder_0)
#100-199 (folder_1)
#...
MAX_FILES_PER_DIR = 100    

pngDirectory = Path()
pngFiles = pngDirectory.glob('*.png')   #find all png files in directory
for pngFile in pngFiles:
    fileNumber = int(pngFile.name.split('.')[0])            #get number from filename
    folderNumber = int(fileNumber / MAX_FILES_PER_DIR)      #find which folder it belongs in
    #create folder to put files in and mkdir if it doesn't exist
    currentFolder = pngDirectory / "folder_{}".format(folderNumber)
    if not currentFolder.exists():
        currentFolder.mkdir()
    #move your png file into that folder
    pngFile.rename(currentFolder / pngFile.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), which provides methods for looping over the content of a folder.

With Path.iterdir() you should be able to loop over your images. With Path.mkdir() you should be able to create the folders you want. For moving files you can use [Path.replace()](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/#moving-and-deleting-files).

Alternatively you can use system commands for doing this using [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).